# Metric with Harmonic Coefficient and Stress-Energy Tensor in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I have two question:

1. Is there any possible implies or interest to use in general relativity a metric whose coefficients are harmonic functions?
2. What is the meaning (physical) if the stress-energy tensor ($T_{ij}$) has the components that are harmonic functions?

Comment: You're talking about a periodic universe, right? Or solutions of Laplace's equations for the tensor components?

Comment: I'm talking about the solution of Laplace's equations

Comment: Where the components of the metric tensor are functions that satisfy the Laplace's equation (i.e. $\nabla^2 f=0$)

Comment: This is an interesting and somewhat unusual question - could you say anything about the physical motivation?

Comment: I found a result of differential geometry about isometric "totally umbilical" immersion with a special kind of Liouville's metric (i.e. with harmonic coefficient), but now I would like to know if there may be a possible application in General Relativity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer to the first part of your question. A metric with harmonic coefficients is for example the [FLRW metric for an universe with positive curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric#Hyperspherical_coordinates). In this case the metric takes the form ($c=1$):

$$ds^2 = dt^2 - a^2(t) \left(dr^2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \sin(r\sqrt{k}) d\Omega^2 \right)$$

Comment: Can it applies also in isothermal coordinates (always considering harmonic metric coefficients)?

Comment: @AlexanderPigazzini Honestly I don't know, I haven't studied the FLRW metric in isothermal coordinates, so I don't know what you would get if you make that change of coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...one more thing...and the FLRW in (1+1) or (1+2) dimension?